# PixelFormat convertation trouble

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, aforge, pixelformat

this is my code:

```
BitmapData bmpData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
UnmanagedImage img = new UnmanagedImage(bmpData);
//MAIN BLOCK
BayerDithering filter = new BayerDithering();
img = new UnmanagedImage(img.ImageData, img.Width, img.Height, img.Stride, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
filter.ApplyInPlace(img);
//END MAIN BLOCK
bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

This is result: **[screenshot](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6436/63489928.0/0_112c44_8107b87a_orig.png)**

Why result is not complited Oo? And what i must change **only** in "*MAIN BLOCK*"?

Comment: I have doubts that this code produces the screenshot you've given. You're using `img` and `_img` separately..

Comment: sorry, this is my lapse

Comment: Youre locking it at 24bpp and your filter is applying it at 8bpp.. what do you expect the result would be?

Comment: i can't change anything outside "main block"/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
img = new UnmanagedImage(..., img.Stride, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
```

That's the statement where the problem started.  You are passing the pixel data and the stride of a 24bpp image but lied and said it is an 8bpp image.  The result is still a 24bpp image and a thoroughly confused filter.

This cannot work, conversion from 24bpp to 8bpp is far more involved.  The 8bpp image won't only have a different pixel format and stride, it also requires a color table (aka palette).  Creating a good color table with 256 colors that produces a reasonably matching 8bpp image is difficult.

You'll need one of the classes in the AForge.Imaging.ColorReduction namespace to get that job done.